# Getting ActionView::MissingTemplate at / error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out why I'm getting an error on this rails tutorial. I've restarted everything (computer, web brick, sublime Text, etc). Any help is appreciated.

**controllers/visitors_controller.rb**

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController 

def new
@owner = Owner.new
render 'visitors/new'
end

end
```

**models/owner.rb**

```
 class Owner

def name
 name = 'Foobar Kadigan'
 end

def birthdate

birthdate = Date.new(1990, 12, 22)
end

def countdown

today = Date.today

birthday = Date.new(today.year, birthdate.month, birthdate.day) 

 if birthday > today

countdown = (birthday - today).to_i

else

countdown = (birthday.next_year - today).to_i

end 

end
end
```

**view/visitors/new.html.erb**

```
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Welcome to the home of <%= @owner.name %>.</p>
  <p>I was born on <%= @owner.birthdate %>.</p>
  <p>Only <%= @owner.countdown %> days until my birthday!</p>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
 LearnRails::Application.routes.draw do 
 root to: 'visitors#new'
 end
```

Edit: Took out

```
 render 'visitors/new'
```

and now getting this error:

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate at /
 Missing template visitors/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb,       :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
   * "/Users/waymond/Rails_App/learn-rails/app/views"
   * "/Users/waymond/Rails_App/learn-rails"
   * "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

"view" in "view/visitors/new.html.erb" should be plural i.e. "views/visitors/new.html.erb"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Try what Justin suggests?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your line `render 'visitors/new'` in your controller. With `visitors/new`, it's looking for file `_new.html.erb` instead of `new.html.erb`. You should use `render "new"`

Comment: Actually try taking out the render 'visitors/new' line entirely.  Since rails should renter that by default.

Comment: Yes, it does. I wrote that to demonstrate

Comment: I took out 'visitors/new' and got the error message that I updated in my post.

Comment: try renaming your view to '_new.html.erb'

Answer (score 0):

I started from the beginning and it worked this time around. I used the same code as my original post. Thanks to those with suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

change "views/visitors/new.html.erb" to "views/visitors/new.erb"

This stops the Missing Template error since the template will be used for all mimes.